# Cannot convert value of type '() -> Data?' to expected argument type 'Data'

Tags: swift, uiimage

```
if let imageData = UIImage.pngData(image) {
    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
    post["imageFile"] = imageFile
    post.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
    }
}
```

This code keep showing the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> Data?' to expected argument type 'Data'

I thought `UIImage.pngData` will just return value type of `Data?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is incorrect. You need to call `pngData` on the `UIImage` instance.

```
if let imageData = image.pngData() {
```